# Using multiple Foundation 3 tabs on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, zurb-foundation

I have an example of what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/m4BZt/

I have such a template (I'm using `Backbone` library):

```
<div class="four columns productView">
    <dl class="tabs">
        <dd class="active"><a href="#<%= Id %>-tab1">Purchase</a></dd>
        <dd class=""><a href="#<%= Id %>-tab2">Specification</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <ul class="tabs-content">
        <li class="active" id="<%= Id %>-tab1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300&amp;text=[img]">
            <h4><%= Title %></h4>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="blue small nice button radius">Add to Cart »</a>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li id="<%= Id %>-tab2">
            <h4><%= Title %></h4>
            <p><%= Description %></p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="blue small nice button radius">Add to Cart »</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But this breaks. Somehow It `doesn't show me second tab content` despite it `changes tab visually` and adds hash sign and model `Id with -tab[1|2] postfix` to the `url bar`.

Maybe I missed something? How do I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your naming conventions are off, the Tab and Content must be as follows:

> If you want functional tabs, just be sure that each tab is linked to an ID, and that the corresponding tab has an ID of #tabnameTab. -[Foundation Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/tabs.php)

Tab: `href="#ID"`

Content: `id="IDTab"`

Try something like the code below.

```
<div class="four columns productView">
    <dl class="tabs">
        <dd class="active"><a href="#<%= Id %>Buy">Purchase</a></dd>
        <dd class=""><a href="#<%= Id %>Spec">Specification</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <ul class="tabs-content">
        <li class="active" id="<%= Id %>BuyTab">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300&amp;text=[img]">
            <h4><%= Title %></h4>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="blue small nice button radius">Add to Cart »</a>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li id="<%= Id %>SpecTab">
            <h4><%= Title %></h4>
            <p><%= Description %></p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="blue small nice button radius">Add to Cart »</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably things are much worse: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564558/how-do-i-integrate-foundation-3-in-an-amd-manner

Comment: What you are showing me are two completely different issues. I suggest you isolate them and fix them independently. Judging by the foundation docs you clearly have your naming conventions wrong: "If you want functional tabs, just be sure that each tab is linked to an ID, and that the corresponding tab has an ID of #tabnameTab."